# why does a jquery plugin chained without parentheses return the function instead of obj for This?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this, chaining

I am creating a basic jquery plugin, I've already wrote some and quite familiar with it, but for expanding my plugin and adding some other methods to it, I like to use a dot like this:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {

};

$.fn.myplugin.render = function () {
    alert("hi");
    alert(this);
};

$("#test").myplugin.render();
```

the problem is that `this` returns the function instead of my jquery object, hmmm? any explanation or workaround?
I don't want to change to `myplugin_render` or call `myplugin().render()`

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuHT9/)

Comment: You are calling function in a context of `myplugin` why do you expect its context to be something else? People usually use `$(blah).plugin('method')` to call plugin's methods.

Comment: We could probably post an answer creating something with data() to hold the element so it's accessible in methods chained to the  plugin, but it just seems so much easier to not do it this way at all and just call the plugin directly, so  I'm not sure we should ?

Comment: There is a trick that works in modern browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6LXLU/5/ But if they ask you plz do not tell it was me who showed you this. :)

Comment: wow, thanks @YuryTarabanko!! what a way, probably I won't use it too. but it was genius, why not post it as a answer so I can accept it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this by defining your plugin to be a property with a custom getter that will return plugin instance with all its methods binded to the original jQuery instance. Beware this method has a few downsides:

- This wont work in IE<9. And there is no way to polyfill this syntax.
- It will create a new plugin object on every call. Might be a performance issue.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6LXLU/6/

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = { //methods and properties you want
        render: function() {        
            alert(this[0].outerHTML);
        },
        log: function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    },
        makePlugin = function(ctx) {
            var result = {}, name, value;

            for(name in methods) { //copy all properties
                value = methods[name];
                if('function' == typeof value) { //bind functions to current ctx.
                    value = $.proxy(value, ctx); //or value.bind(ctx) :)    
                }
                result[name] = value;                    
            }

            return result;
        };
    Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'myplugin', { //define a readonly property
        get: function() {
            return makePlugin(this); //create a binded copy of the plugin           
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$("#test").myplugin.render(); 
$("#test").myplugin.log();
```